# Connection to Hadoop from Talend

Tags: hadoop, talend, talend-mdm

I am trying to connect to Hadoop from Talend with Thdfsinput but when I run the job I get this error :

[image: Error in Talend]

I am using Talend Open Studio for Big Data V7.3
and Java version 8.

Comment: Hello Hamza. Did you check your JVM settings for the studio and your JAVA_HOME system variable ?

Comment: hi carassus , yes i checked it , there is a missing jars so i tried to add it but it s not working

Comment: Did you have a look at this post about importing libraries : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290609/how-to-add-third-party-libraries-to-talend-project

Comment: yes , I did but it doesn't work , i don"t know if prblm of jars version or something else .

Comment: And can you put in the post description all the following info : java version indicated by the command "java -version", the java version used by the studio and the Talend Studio version ?
If the import doesnt work the problem might be in a minor version difference somewhere

Comment: i use talend open studio for big data V7.3 and java -version used is java 8.

Comment: Can you put the info in your post (use the "edit" button) ? And can you put the whole version ? And can you pu the version used by Talend (it should be in Window>Preferences>Installed JRE) ?

Comment: He probably can't because of rep restrictions? Anyway, I edited the post, however I'm afraid we MUST see the complete stacktrace to help.

Comment: solved guys thank u carassus :) , the solution is go to Window -> Show view -> Talend -> Modules and install jars that you need